# Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 1 : Lightning Component Framework

Tags: lightning-aura-components, certification, platform-developer-1

For the **Salesforce Certified Platform Developer 1 exam**, these two points are mentioned as part of the study guide but I am not sure at what level of technical understanding you need on these two topics specifically for the intent of passing this exam.

> - Describe the benefits of the Lightning Component framework
> - Describe the resources that can be contained in a Lightning
>     Component

Do you need to be very thorough with aura framework like how one should be with VF framework or the questions test only your basic understanding of this lightning comp framework ?

Has anyone who has completed/attended this exam in the recent times, throw some light on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the transition track from advanced developer to the platform developer II exam. So I did not take the platform developer 1 exam, but got the certification all the same.

Take into consideration that these exams are reviewed and extended every release and it is thus likely that the questions on developing lightning will increase and so will their detail or complexity from what it may be now.

Having done nearly all other certifications I would interpret it like this:

- Know how to compare Lightning to Visualforce
- Know where you can use Lightning components and applications
- Read the high level help/documentation introduction to see what benefits are mentioned to both end users and developers.
- Understand how you develop (and deploy?) a lightning component
- Developer a hello-world component and try to get some data from a controller
- Do any trailhead modules on lightning components (may include the point above)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience in other certifications, the "Describe the ..." type certification requirements will mean you need to understand how the feature works but you will not be required to actually write code.

I say this without having taken the exam yet.

Someone who has taken the exam will have agreed to the test taker agreement which requires them to not give away anything material about the exam. As such, they would be hesitant to reply to your request for "shedding light". Doing so could jeopardize their certification.

Comment: " jeopardize their certification"..This is too far fetched and sounds unrealistic...Even now as I type, I could see dozens of posts related to certification examinations to the right side of my screen and folks respond all the time...I agree threads related to asking for answers should not be enteratained but I don't believe OP is looking for that...Just my 2 cents

Comment: I agree they wouldn't necessarily be jeopardizing their cert. But "shed light" is vague. How exactly a person sheds light is more important. I wasn't saying the OP was soliciting for specific answers, but IMO "shed light" is firmly in the grey area. If a person were to offer up questions, though, they are definitely risking their cert.

Comment: Based on your response, it seemed worthwhile to push this to a new question here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96298/can-i-lose-my-salesforce-certification-by-disclosing-information-about-the-exam